# yarn add - 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I have published a private package in my company as `@company/package-name`, I can see it in our github repository.

After that, I did `yarn add @company/package-name` in another project and I got:

```
➤ YN0027: @company/package-name@unknown can't be resolved to a satisfying range
➤ YN0035: The remote server failed to provide the requested resource
➤ YN0035:   Response Code: 403 (Forbidden)
➤ YN0035:   Request Method: GET
➤ YN0035:   Request URL: https://npm.pkg.github.com/@company%2fname
```

It is weird, I can publish but I cannot install it.
Do you have any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the source of errors.

The checkbox `Inherit access from source repository (recommended)` was unchecked in the package settings page.

I have enabled it, and now, we can publish (also with --experimental) and also download this new package.

Thank you `Trond Glomnes` for your help.

Comment: Where is this checkbox that you are referring to? Im facing the same issue with a private package as well.

Comment: You need to have access to the private package. You can use https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/configuring-a-packages-access-control-and-visibility to find the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like yarn is causing issue. followed the below steps and that did the trick.

```
npm uninstall –g yarn

npm cache clean –force

npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Thank, but it does not work.